# Kentico 10 time zones not working as expected

Tags: azure, kentico

I have a Kentico 10 website that's hosted on Azure. I have configured timezones on the website by following the instructions [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/configuring-time-zones) in the documentation. I have enabled timezones in (global) settings and applied the desired timezone to both the server and the site as below:

[image]

I have even set the user's timezone to the one I want:

[image]

However, in the pages app, when I go to a page's publish from and publish to properties (under the Form tab) and hit the 'now' link, the date and time that gets populated there always appears to be a UTC date and time.

[image]

This is not ideal and is confusing for website users. I would have expected the date and time that gets populated here upon clicking 'now' to be the time as specified in the time zone settings above.

I am not aware of the intricacies of hosting an Kentico 10 website on Azure and I couldn't find any documentation suggesting anything. I am aware that azure uses UTC times by default but not sure how or why that would be affecting the time zone settings specified here.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Server Time Zone setting reflects your server's time zone. I believe Azure's services run in GMT, so try changing your Server Time Zone setting from **(UTC+10.00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney** to **(UTC+00.00) Greenwich Mean Time (UTC)**.